# Vue js: How to hide button

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm new to Vue js in this code below , i wanted to hide button "Clear Filter" when nothing selected and show the button only when function " selectedAnswer(index)" called so that it will show only when filter applied otherwise it should be hided , is there a  way to do it in my code?
and thanks in advance

```html
<template>
  <div class="container" width=800px>
    <b-row>
      <b-col cols="8">
        <h1> Recently Asked </h1>
        <ul class="container-question" v-for="(question1,index) in questions" :key="index">
          <li>
            {{question1.question}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </b-col>
      <b-button class="outline-primaryy" style="margin:auto;" @click="ClearFilter" >Clear Filter</b-button>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        questions: [],
        answered: null,
        index: 0,
        selectedIndex: null,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectedAnswer(index) {
        this.selectedIndex = index;
        this.questions = this.questions.filter((question) => question.incorrect_answers.includes(index))
        console.log(index)
      },
      ClearFilter() {
        this.questions = this.unmutated
      },
      watch: {
        question1: {
          handler() {
            this.selectedIndex = null;
            this.answered = false;
          },
        },
      },
    },
    mounted: function() {
      fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=medium&type=multiple', {
          method: 'get'
        })
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((jsonData) => {
          this.questions = jsonData.results
          this.unmutated = jsonData.results;
        })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [check this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `v-if="selectedIndex"` to your btn element.
ie

```
<b-button v-if="selectedIndex" class="outline-primaryy" style="margin:auto;" @click="ClearFilter" >Clear Filter</b-button
```

Comment: i tried this but when i click on clear filter it should disappear again but it didn't

Comment: @sara97 You would have to set `selectedIndex` to `null` in your `ClearFilter` method.